Как сделать Push репозитория на гитхаб если он весит больше 2 ГБ
Делаю игру на юнити в команде скачал все что нужно и узнал что максимальный размер пуша репоситория используя LFC -2ГБ(Бесплатно) подскажите что делать проекты нанити весят много, наш конечно 2д но думаю он точно будет больше 2ГБ

Пуша, а не пушей. Вместо одного большого пуша делайте много маленьких, да и всё, наверное?

Храни в репозитории только необходимые для запуска проекта файлы и папки. К этому не относятся: изображения, видео, текстуры и т.д. Их храните отдельно. Также не надо включать в проект файлы сторонних библиотек, которые могут занимать много места. В общем старайтесь класть  в гит лишь то, что вы разрабатываете/правите, а всё, что остаётся без изменений не помещать в Git, просто хранить весь проект отдельным бекапом на чёрный день. У клиента сайт был (каталог) на 80 гигов без бд, в репозиторий ушло пол гига.

@ViVi не надо обижать ассеты, они тоже заслуживают быть контролируемыми через систему контроля версий, специпльно для этого LFS и придумали

Файл .gitignore (настроенный) не забыл кинуть в папку с проектом?
